# Why is the WinForms editor causing so much code change?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I open the WinForms designer and I make a simple change like changing the button text. After saving, a lot of unintended code changes occur:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have the `<ForceDesignerDpiUnaware>true</ForceDesignerDpiUnaware>` configuration option in my project file so the location of the elements isn't changing, just some of the syntax as shown in the images above. Why is this happening and what can I do to avoid this?

Comment: Are these changes happening in the designer.cs file, or in the normal code behind file for your forms? Either way it's best to ignore them and not try to fight them as that is a never ending battle.

Comment: They happen in the designer.cs file and resx file

Comment: Anything that happens in the designer.cs files is out of your hands and can be affected by a lot of different things. It can be reviewed before committing, but ultimately it should be considered an auto-generated file. As for the resource file getting changes, it's possibly connected due to a change in your references. Have you enabled global usings before this change was noticed?